# Convert observe .value to .childAdded in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I'm having some problems with this bit of code that is loading data from firebase database into an array. Since this is inside of viewDidLoad I have to empty my array `food = []` before loading the data into it, if I don't then it will duplicate all the objects and I will have double duplicates the second time it loads, triple the third time and etc... However this was not a good fix for multiple reasons so what I would like is that it would only add new objects from the database with `.childAdded` however if I just switch out `.value` with `.childAdded` it will crash, I get a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on this line: `let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]`. I am pretty new to swift and don't know how to fix this, would really appreciate some help.

```
let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")
let storage = Storage.storage()

parentRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

            // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
            print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

        } else {

            //Clears array so that it does not load duplicates
            food = []

            // DATA WAS FOUND
            for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

                let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

                //Defines variables for labels
                let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
                let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String
                let downloadURL = dict["Image"] as? String

                let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL!)

                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

                    let recipeImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                    food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!))
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Update your code with this line to avoid crash `if let dict = user_snap.value as? [String: String?] { } `. Also check `user_snap ` object, for its type. As your app crashes, so i am sure  that it doesn't have dictionary object.

Comment: @Surjeet What do i put inside of `{ }` ?

Comment: Your code after the commented line 'Define variables for labels'. I have given you updated version of second line inside for loop

Comment: @Surjeet ok added all code after the comment into the brackets, it did not crash however my tableView is empty now and so is the array.

Comment: @Surjeet in other words: the code inside the brackets doesn't run, it skips over it.

Comment: That means you didn't receive a dictionary from `user_snap.value`. You need to check which `dataType you receive from user_snap.value`. Or show your table structure, then i can help you.

Comment: @Surjeet here's what `user_snap` contains and `dict` is empty: https://imgur.com/a/BkiXc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]
```

Instead of

```
let dict = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
```

and maybe you can do null test :

```
let dict = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

if let recipeName = dict["Name"] as String!, let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as String!, let downloadURL = dict["Image"] as String! {
    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL)

    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

        let recipeImage = UIImage(data: data!)

        food.append(Element(name: recipeName, description: recipeDescription, image: recipeImage!, downloadURL: downloadURL))
        self.tableView.reloadData()                        
    }                    
}else {
    print("Error! Could not decode data")                    
}
```

Comment: Yess man you're awesome! Thank you, however you left some of my code out and changed some variable names so i edited and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

try this. It should work

```
for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

let dict = child.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>

//.....
}
```

Comment: I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` on `let dict = child.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>` and in debugger it says `Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString'`