# Swift delete image from firebase storage

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that deletes an object from my firebase database by swiping the tableView cell, however, my tableView cells also contain images that are saved in firebase storage, I would like for the image to be deleted from the storage too when the data is deleted from the database, how can I accomplish this?

**Code for deleting:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let name = food[indexPath.row].name
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")

        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Name").queryEqual(toValue: name).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            //Removes deleted cell from firebase
            snapshot.ref.removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, reference) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("There has been an error: \(error)")
                }
                //Removes deleted cell from array
                food.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                //Removes deleted cell from tableView
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**Code for loading:**

```
let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")
    let storage = Storage.storage()

    parentRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

            // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
            print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

        } else {

            //Clears array so that it does not load duplicates
            food = []

            // DATA WAS FOUND
            for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

                let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

                //Defines variables for labels
                let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
                let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String
                let downloadURL = dict["Image"] as? String

                let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL!)

                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

                    let recipeImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                    food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!))
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Would also really appreciate if someone could also help me with this other question I asked about this same app: [Convert observe .value to .childAdded in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549312/7109256)

**Edit:**

I have added the URL to the array when loading the objects from firebase:

```
food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!, downloadURL: downloadURL!))
```

And this is what I'm trying to use to delete:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let storageRef = storage.reference()
let desertRef = storageRef.child(food[indexPath.row].downloadURL)

//Removes image from storage
desertRef.delete { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        // File deleted successfully
    }
}
```

I don't think it's finding the image, however... I get this error:

> Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13010 "Object https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recipe-app-1b76e.appspot.com/o/B74F604B-68FD-45BB-ABDB-150B03E83A2A.png?alt=media&token=ae2643c4-6479-4dc8-b389-d04caac98392 does not exist." UserInfo={object=https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recipe-app-1b76e.appspot.com/o/B74F604B-68FD-45BB-ABDB-150B03E83A2A.png?alt=media&token=ae2643c4-6479-4dc8-b389-d04caac98392, bucket=recipe-app-1b76e.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
>     "error": {
>       "code": 404,
>       "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object"
>     }
>   },

Comment: [Firebase Delete Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/delete-files) 
Maybe workaround, your food object add download url and delete storageRef.

let desertRef = storageRef.child(food.downloadUrl)
desertRef.delete...

Comment: @EmreYILMAZ hey please look at the edit in the bottom of my question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved it! Heres what worked for me:

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let url = food[indexPath.row].downloadURL
let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: url)

//Removes image from storage
storageRef.delete { error in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        // File deleted successfully
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

create reference based on image location.

```
// Create a reference to the file to delete
let imageRef = storageRef.child("image.png")

// Delete the file
imageRef.delete { error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // File deleted successfully
  }
}
```

add the above code before following line

`food.remove(at: indexPath.row)`

[Storing/Downloading/Deleting images or videos Using Firebase Cloud Storage](http://iosrevisited.blogspot.com/2017/10/storingdownloading-images-videos-firebase-cloudstorage.html)!

Comment: hey please look at the edit in the bottom of my question